# Where is my mbox located at?

Tags: macos, terminal, email, command-line

The Terminal keeps telling me I have mail from scripts that are hitting errors, and then when I scroll through the messages to read them, it tells me afterwards `saved x messages in mbox`.

Where is my mbox, I cannot find it?

Answer (score 11):

Open Terminal and type `mail`

For example, I created a test message for the purposes of this answer.  Now, when I type the `mail` command:

```
mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/allan": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 allan@Allans-iMac.ho  Sun Mar  6 23:34  14/464   "test"
?
```

You can type `?` for help, or just select the message number, in this case `1` to read the message.  If you want to delete the message, type `d1`.  When you are finished type `quit`.

**To go back to a message that has been saved in your `mbox`, just issue the command:**

`mail -f ~/mbox` and it will open the mailbox of the currently logged in user.  From there, you will be able to access read/reply/delete to mail that no longer shows up as *unread*. Please note that the "f" option has to be lower-case.

For a full listing of commands, just type `man mail` for the manual pages or go to [mail command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_Mail.htm) for reference.

Comment: ok, what I was doing before is typing mail and then scrolling through the messages with the `ENTER` key. then it tells me it saved the messages in my box but I have no idea where that is. and the messages are no longer there when I type `mail` again

Comment: Ok...I updated my answer to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 5):

box can be found at `/Users/<username>/mbox` and it is just an archived version of the mail, which can be accessed by `mail -f` and then deleted through the normals means of the mail program